# Python No module found error while importing .py from another folder

Tags: python, import, initialization, modulenotfounderror

I have followed a [wildly accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), which did not work for me.
Here is what I have:
Folder structure:

Demo folder

[image]

Fold1

[image]

Fold2

[image]

Also, the `__init__.py` is an empty file. Has nothing in it.

Objective: import `customfunction.py` file from `Demo` or `Fold1` into `Fold2`

Code in `MainFile.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import Demo.customfunctions
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Demo'
```

Comment: Put the `Mainfile.py` (or whatever you run initially) into the main directory!

Comment: @KlausD. you mean in `Demo` folder? The idea was to have the common files in the parent directory, in this case, `Demo` and I can use this in all sub-folders.

Comment: The idea of Python is quite the opposite. The folder of the module you run becomes the import base and you can't import above it (without manually adapting the PYTHONPATH). All modules to import go there or below.

Comment: @KlausD. I looked at one of the highest-voted answers in the link I provided and was following the same. For past couple of years, the issue I am facing is this. I have a list of standard functions and I want to store them in one common `.py` file and share across my programs. This helps me avoid copied of it and helps me develop the main function file. I can update this on `Github` for my personal tracking. Do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a proper combination of your current working directory, the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and the path to the script.

If your current working directory is `Downloads`, you can run the `Demo.Fold2.MainFile` module without modifying `PYTHONPATH`. I.e.

```
> python -m Demo.Fold2.MainFile
```

Or you can run the `Demo\Fold2\MainFile.py` file if you set `PYTHONPATH` to the current working directory. I.e.

```
> :: relative PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=.
> python Demo\Fold2\MainFile.py
>
> :: or absolute PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=c:\absolute\path\to\Downloads
> python Demo\Fold2\MainFile.py
```

If your current working directory is `Demo`, you can run the `Fold2.MainFile` module if you set `PYTHONPATH` to the `Downloads` directory. I.e.

```
> :: relative PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=..
> python -m Fold2.MainFile
>
> :: or absolute PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=c:\absolute\path\to\Downloads
> python -m Fold2.MainFile
```

or the `Fold2\MainFile.py` file. I.e.

```
> :: relative PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=..
> python Fold2\MainFile.py
>
> :: or absolute PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=c:\absolute\path\to\Downloads
> python Fold2\MainFile.py
```

If your current working directory is `Fold2`, you can run the `MainFile` module if you set `PYTHONPATH` to the `Downloads` directory. I.e.

```
> :: relative PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=..\..
> python -m MainFile
>
> :: or absolute PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=c:\absolute\path\to\Downloads
> python -m MainFile
```

or the `MainFile.py` file. I.e.

```
> :: relative PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=..\..
> python MainFile.py
>
> :: or absolute PYTHONPATH
> set PYTHONPATH=c:\absolute\path\to\Downloads
> python MainFile.py
```

Comment: I am a beginner. If you don't mind, I am not familiar what this `Pythonpath`. I am totally lost it here. I really appreciate it if you could explain.  The first question is, do I have to include this python path in my `MainFile.py` ? I tried this but got the error: `PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/Downloads python3 Demo/Fold2/MainFile.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Mainland, `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable that augments the default search path for module files (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Environment variables are set outside of your Python files. On Windows, you can either set them from the Command Prompt or via a graphical user interface. Take a look e.g. at the two top answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3701646/542196 or at the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: Also please note that you have to adjust the absolute path to `Downloads` according to your environment. It may be something like `C:\Users\Mainland\Downloads`.